# Cannot run ctl on Linux for pNFS

Tags: linux, nfs, nfs4

I want to install pNFS server. I install ctl from source code. But when I run command `ctl -u`, the error below occur:

> /proc/fs/pnfs_block/ctl: No such file or directory

I run linux 4.6, the ctl package downloads from the source http://git.linux-nfs.org/?p=bhalevy/pnfsd-block-ctl.git;a=snapshot;h=b8c5680e2e3588ed3e4e35db85e9813c0482ba1d;sf=tgz. Do you know how to fix it

Comment: Are you running 32 bit on 64 bit system? http://askubuntu.com/questions/133389/no-such-file-or-directory-but-the-file-exists

Comment: I run 64 bit, but I think my actual problem come from module PNFS_BLOCK